# How to validate params using props in React

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am using code `this.props.params.key` for reading params from url, param name is `key.` From ESlint i am getting.

> [eslint] 'params' is missing in props validation (react/prop-types)

How to fix this warrning? How to valildate params in props?

For validate variable from props, for example `this.props.size` i am using:

```
CLASSNAME.propTypes = {
    size: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}
```

And for params?

Thanks for any help

Edit:
Key from params is MD5 hash.

Comment: is params an Object? You can set type object in proptypes for params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an object "shape" for params:

```
params: PropTypes.shape({
    key: PropTypes.string.isRequired
})
```

So your complete proptypes would be:

```
CLASSNAME.propTypes = {
    size: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    params: PropTypes.shape({
        key: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }) // add .isRequired here if "params" is required
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CLASSNAME.propTypes = {
    param: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}
```

This should solvethe warning